# Can we achieve Limit functionality similar to database, from Maps.filteKey/Value method provided in Guava library

Tags: java, performance, guava

Need any inputs on how can we define limit as parameter to Maps.filterKeys methods provided by Google Guava Library so that once the limit is reached there is no need to iterate furthur.

I have following requirement where I have Map and Predicate(Filter in this case).

Like as follows Maps.filterKeys(myMap, myPredicate);

Map has approximate 5000 key,values where I want once predicate is satisfied for certain number of times. I do not want to iterate more instead return the filteredMap.

Is there any way out or we need to ask guava team to add same as input parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is 0 iteration going on in `Maps.filterKeys().` [The javadoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#filterKeys%28java.util.Map,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) explains it:

> Returns a map containing the mappings in `unfiltered` whose keys
>   satisfy a predicate. The returned map is a live view of `unfiltered`;
>   changes to one affect the other.

So, it doesn't returning a filtered copy of the map, but a filtered view.

If you want a filtered copy, then you'll have to iterate over the entrySet() of the filtered map and fill a new one, until your limit is reached.

Comment: Thanks got the point but can we get a view with limited entries. Since in predicate I am not able to specify a limit. Or else I need to iterate over it as suggested by Seelenvirtuose.

Comment: That wouldn't make sense. Let's say you have a map with 1,000,000 entries, and you create a view that only retains the key starting with 'A', limited to 10 entries. How could the view decide what `filteredMap.get("Animal")` should return? Neither `Maps.filtered()` nor `Map.get()` performs an iteration. So they can't limit anything. So you need to iterate first to create a limited copy of the filtered map.

Comment: That said, you could probably use `Iterables.limit(Maps.filterKeys(map, predicate).entrySet(), limit)` to get you an `Iterable` of entries to start with.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the filterKeys methods in the class Maps all return a map implementation that is only a decorator for the specified map, which then uses the specified predicate for filtering. There is no iteration process done. You must explicitely iterate yourself over the map entries, so you can (and must) implement the behavior yourself.